# Intel vPro issue. Can't connect to PC

Tags: intel

At the moment I experience issue wit vPro.
Have five PCs with Intel vPro. Pcs have the same configuration, they are identical.
Can't connect to PC1.
I can connect to this PC1 when it is turn on (supply and windows)
But I can't connect to this PC1 when it is off (supply on, windows off)
have following error
http://prntscr.com/bk1a8i
I use Manageability Commander Tool

What can cause the issue ?

please help
thanks